# JavaScript clock not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an updating JavaScript clock on my webpage. The problem I'm having is that, while the value itself updates (I use `alert(timeNow)` to show the value and make sure it's updating), the clock on the website doesn't. I was just wondering if there was something I was missing, or if I've just happened to come across something that I can't quite do. I'd prefer if there was a way to do it using jQuery, as I understand that a little better than normal JavaScript.

Javascript:

```js
function updateClock() {
  var thisDate = new Date();
  if (thisDate.getHours() > 11 && thisDate.getHours() != 0) {
    var Hours = Math.abs(thisDate.getHours() - 12);
    var AmPm = "PM"
  } else {
    var Hours = thisDate.getHours()
    var AmPm = "AM"
  }

  if (thisDate.getMinutes() < 10) {
    var Mins = "0" + thisDate.getMinutes();
  } else {
    var Mins = thisDate.getMinutes();
  };

  var timeNow = thisDate.getDate() + "/" + (thisDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + thisDate.getFullYear() + " " + Hours + ":" + Mins + " " + AmPm;
  return timeNow;
};
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

$("span#time").append(updateClock());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: `$("span#time").append(updateClock());` is supposed to be within function `updateClock`

Comment: @MeteorZero No it shouldn't, that's infinite recursion.

Comment: Are sorry I didn't notice this `append(updateClock())`

Comment: What did I mean is this `$("span#time").append(timeNow);`

Comment: If you want to use jquery [https://momentjs.com/] have a look. Example : https://codepen.io/gab/pen/KLhgr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not consuming the return value of `updateClock` function, thus the updated time is not reflecting.

You should update the text of time span

*Use*

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("span#time").text(updateClock());
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the time in the function `updateClock()`. What you actually want to do is to set it into the DOM at the end of `updateClock()`. Here is an updated example:

```
function updateClock() {
    var thisDate = new Date();
    if (thisDate.getHours() > 11 && thisDate.getHours() != 0) {
        var Hours = Math.abs(thisDate.getHours() - 12);
        var AmPm = "PM"
    } else {
        var Hours = thisDate.getHours()
        var AmPm = "AM"
    }

    if (thisDate.getMinutes() < 10) {
        var Mins = "0" + thisDate.getMinutes();
    } else {
        var Mins = thisDate.getMinutes();
    };

    var timeNow = thisDate.getDate() + "/" + (thisDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + thisDate.getFullYear() + " " + Hours + ":" + Mins + " " + AmPm;
    $("span#time").text(timeNow);
}

setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

---

You could of course also just use the returned value of `updateClock()` to update the DOM. In this way, you would separate the DOM manipulation and the JavaScript time calculation. @Satpal described this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{

            
            goforit();

});
 
var dayarray=new Array ("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                           "Thursday","Friday","Saturday")

            var montharray=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June",
                           "July","August","September","October","November","December")

            function getthedate() {
                d = new Date();
                d.setUTCFullYear(2004);
                d.setUTCMonth(1);
                d.setUTCDate(29);
                d.setUTCHours(2);
                d.setUTCMinutes(45);
                d.setUTCSeconds(26);

            var mydate=new Date()
            var year=mydate.getYear()
            if (year < 1000)
            year+=1900
            var day=mydate.getDay()
            var month=mydate.getMonth()
            var daym=mydate.getDate()
            if (daym<10)
            daym="0"+daym
            var hours=mydate.getHours()
            var minutes=mydate.getMinutes()
            var seconds=mydate.getSeconds()
            var dn=""
            if (hours>=12)
            dn=""
            if (hours>12){
            hours=hours-12
            }
            if (hours==0)
            hours=12
            if (minutes<=9)
            minutes="0"+minutes
            if (seconds<=9)
            seconds="0"+seconds
            //Hire change font size
            var cdate=""
              + mydate.toLocaleString()
              +""

            if (document.all)
            document.all.clock.innerHTML=cdate
            else if (document.getElementById)
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=cdate
            else
            document.write(cdate)
            }
            if (!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
            getthedate()
            function goforit()
            {
            if (document.all||document.getElementById)
            setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SPAN id=clock style="display:block"></SPAN>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function() {
   $("span#time").text(moment(new Date()).format('DD/M/YYYY LTS'));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<span id="time"></span>
```